# Can't install Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: nvidia, 15.04

I have the gtx670 and I'm trying to get any of the Nvidia drivers installed. No matter which one I try to install, be it nvidia-current or any of these numbers from the Synaptic Package Manager.

As soon as I install them, reboot, I'm stuck in an infinite crash-reboot loop. I have to do a recovery start, go into console and do sudo apt-get purge nividia* to get it working again.

Only driver that seem to work flawlessly is the Nouvuem one.

What can I do?

Comment: Install the drivers from terminal `sudo apt-get install nvidia-346` and post the output to your question. PLEASE DO NOT POST IT TO COMMENTS!!!

Comment: Output?! Wat? I started with Ubuntu like a week ago. Still a newb.

Comment: I tried your method and got stuck in crash-reboot loop.

Comment: I asked to post output of that command, not just tell it does not work. You run this command on terminal. Copy and paste output of the command TO YOUR QUESTION.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
     sudo apt-get install xorg-xserver-video-all
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: I'm confused, why that?

Comment: It doesn't. No such package can be found.